# Sharepoint framework on premises version

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, spfx

Does anybody know when and if SPFx be available for SharePoint on-premises?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in order to get the SPFx Framework for On-Prem in the next Feature Pack, your SharePoint license requires Software Assurance ?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind. The SharePoint Framework is a lot more than what has been released already (i.e. Web Parts). Over time the capabilities of the SharePoint Framework will expand. This will happen in SharePoint Online first and SharePoint 2016 second. My guess is that the SharePoint 2016 support for SPFx will lag three to six months behind the support in SharePoint Online.

Comment: It's now available since 12 Sept 2017, For more details check [SPFx for SharePoint Server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/16/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SP 2013 or SP 2010, it wont be available. If you are using SP 2016, it will be available via Feature Packs in this year.

According to this link  `The SharePoint Framework works for SharePoint on-premises and SharePoint Online` -  [SPFx overview](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) but MS documentation is bit confusing sometimes so not 100% sure about this.

[SPFx Q&A](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-framework-initial-questions-and-answers) - According to Wictor Wilen's blog post, it will be available in first half of 2017

References-

[SPFx preview](http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/welcome-to-sharepoint-framework-preview/)

[Link to Tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/alexaem/status/798187951289036800)

[SharePoint Framework webinar Q&A follow-up. Part 1 – SharePoint Framework](https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sharepoint-framework-webinar-qa-follow-part-1-sharepoint-framework/)

Comment: Hi Seth, according to the spfx webinar  :"SharePoint Framework will be released as Feature Pack for SharePoint 2016 on-premises. Stay tuned for more information on the release date." So i guess its not available yet or was this pack released already ?

Comment: Yep first half of 2017, so might have to wait till June.

Answer (score 2):

Its the next development step on SPFx since it's general available since February 23 this year in Office 365.

> "Now that we’ve reached general availability, ensuring continued
>   compatibility across versions will be our focus. We’re also working on
>   the next legs of our product roadmap, **including on-premises support**
>   and new development scenarios"

Ref: [SharePoint Framework reaches general availability—build and deploy engaging web parts today](https://blogs.office.com/2017/02/23/sharepoint-framework-reaches-general-availability-build-and-deploy-engaging-web-parts-today/#.WLctTRfvR7Q.twitter)

When is harder to guess, but it wouldn't be a wild guess to say it will be included in feature pack 2 probably released before the summer.

Comment: I'm reading that they will release on-prem in feature pack 2 this fall.  Anyone have a more firm release date? ---- Until then, should I start working with o365, then move my solution to the on-prem version when it's released?

Answer (score 2):

It's available now with Feature Pack 2 for SharePoint Server 2016:

[Announcing Availability of Feature Pack 2 for SharePoint Server 2016](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Announcing-Availability-of-Feature-Pack-2-for-SharePoint-Server/ba-p/105614)

For version compatibility, refer following article:

[SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support)